# Display file names from gitlab on a remote website

Tags: javascript, git, gitlab

Is it possible do display the file name of a specific file inside a git repo on a remote website only using JS?

Comment: Gitlab or Github, you've tagged both. Third party hosted gitlab or your own instance? Browser side JavaScript or server side JavaScript? What research have you done? Have you looked at the API docs?

Comment: Gitlab, the JS is browser side , gitlab is hosted on a privat server

Yes but i dont know how to add the curl request from a console into my JS